# My PC doesn’t sleep in my plan

Tags: windows, windows-10, power, power-management

My monitor is turned off after 1 mintute,But my computer doesn’t sleep after 1 minute(longer than 1 minute) So what should I do!?

Comment: Make a screen shot and then edit your question and put the screen shot in the question. That will work.

Comment: @amirgraphici what was the correct solution? Can you write an answer or comment?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112972/discussion-on-question-by-amir-graphici-my-pc-doesnt-sleep-in-my-plan).

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know what is the solution exactly.But I updated my windows and I installed the antivirus.The antivirus was searching and I saw that the computer went to sleep automatically