# My PC doesn’t sleep automatically

Tags: windows, windows-10, power-management, control-panel

My PC doesn’t sleep automatically. The monitor never turned off
And the PC is set for 3 minutes to go to sleep, but it doesn't sleep.

[image]

Comment: Your image shows the "On battery" settings. Do you really want the computer to sleep on battery?

Comment: @harrymc noooooo

Comment: Better give a fuller screenshot. Also run and post the result file of [Power Efficiency Diagnostics Report](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5148-create-power-efficiency-diagnostics-report-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: I couldn’t post my image.that screen shot isn’t for me.i cant send image Because I don’t know what is 10 reputation

Comment: If you think everything is set up correctly to put it to sleep, and it still isn't, run `powercfg -requests` in the command prompt as admin. This will tell you what is keeping your computer awake.

Comment: Whatever your reputation, you can always edit your post and add links to the new image and the posted file. Post the file on any service such as OneDrive or Dropbox and post its public link.

Comment: @DrZoo I know.The MoUSO core worker process is causing this issue.but I don’t know how to solve that

Comment: MoUSO is related to Windows Updates somehow. Have you ran Windows Updates and restarted your computer? Supposedly the optional update KB4568831 also fixes this issue? You can give that a try too. If you knew that was keeping it awake, that is a very important thing to add into the body of your question. It is currently not present.

Comment: @DrZoo my problem has been solved:))))) https://superuser.com/a/1585168/1214951

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My PC doesn’t sleep in my plan](https://superuser.com/questions/1582274/my-pc-doesn-t-sleep-in-my-plan)

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable sleep functionality through settings. For that:

Search **Power & sleep settings** in the windows search bar. Click **Enter**.

Choose the time that you want the PC to sleep after. See this:

[image]

Choose suitable time after which you want to put it to sleep while plugged in or running in battery power. After the specified time, your PC will go to sleep.

That's it.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: You didn’t understand my question 

Comment: Whatever you've written in the question, I have tried to understand. Yet, you can explain.

Comment: I set a timer for sleep pc.that is 3 mintues.but it doesn’t sleep after 3 mintues

Comment: That is what I too have addressed in my answer. Try doing whatever I have told and tell if if makes any difference.

Comment: I know what are say! I say my pc doesn’t sleep in my plan.i day after 3 mintues it doesn’t sleep

Comment: Showing rude behavior in this forum violates the terms and conditions of the same and doesn't fix issues either. Mend your behaviour and try using less emojis. No one cares about them here :)

Comment: ok ok ok.what should I do to solve my problem?

Comment: The first thing you can do is to ask someone with better english comprehension skill to frame a question for you. Whatever I have written in the answer tells you exactly what you want. I said that tweaking power plan to make PC sleep might not be sufficient if it's not done through settings. Try applying the fix that I suggested and tell me if the problem persists..

Comment: you said how set a plan for sleep and turning off display.but I don’t want to know how to do that because I know that.i said my pc doesn’t sleep after 3 mintues.i want my pc get to sleep after 3 mintues automatically.see the picture in my question

Comment: So, what have you done? Attach a screenshot of your *Power and sleep settings*

Comment: I edit my question but I don’t know why it doesn’t appear

Comment: Because you just removed my edit that I did to bring a little bit of clarity to the question for everyone

Comment: It may be helpful to members looking in to help to review this associated post:   https://superuser.com/questions/1582274/my-pc-doesn-t-sleep-in-my-plan

Comment: @John but my question won’t be solved

Comment: My problem has been solved